# Odd/even page detection fails at the end of each page

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided

I have a document with many (1000+) `tabular` objects which contain figures. I would like the order of the columns of these `tabular`s to flip (1-2-3 -> 3-2-1) depending on whether the `tabular` is on an odd or even page.

To do this, I use the `ifoddpage` package. Each `tabular` object occurs twice, embedded in an `\ifoddpage` conditional statement, which places the `tabular` one way or the other, based on whether the the test determined the page to be even or odd.

Here is a basic example of what I'm doing, but the pictures in the real document have some slight varying sizes:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}  
\chapter{Test}  
% Here starts the block for a single object
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage
\begin{tabular}{m{0.3\textwidth} m{0.3\textwidth} m{0.3\textwidth}}
\missingfigure[figheight=0.185\textheight, figwidth=0.3\textwidth]{} & \missingfigure[figheight=0.185\textheight, figwidth=0.3\textwidth]{} & {\huge \textbf{word}} \newline  \newline \newline {\huge other word} \\ 
\end{tabular}
\else
\begin{tabular}{m{0.3\textwidth} m{0.3\textwidth} m{0.3\textwidth}}
  {\huge \textbf{word}} \newline \newline \newline {\huge other word} & \missingfigure[figheight=0.185\textheight, figwidth=0.3\textwidth]{} & \missingfigure[figheight=0.185\textheight, figwidth=0.3\textwidth]{} \\ 
\end{tabular}
\fi
% Repeat the above block ad nauseam  
\end{document}
```

Now, this works in principle, but in practice the first object on every page is wrong. This is because the `\checkoddpage` places a label for the `\ifoddpage` to refer to. When there is a little room left at the bottom of a page, the `\checkoddpage` can still place the label at the end of the page, while the object is pushed to next page, with the wrong orientation.

So my question is this: is there a way to check whether the next object will be pushed to the next page and compensate for this, or ideally have the `\checkoddpage` label be pushed down according to the object that's to come?

Comment: probably `\leavevmode` before `\checkoddpage` makes it do the right thing

Comment: Note that `a4wide` has long been deprecated.

Comment: \leavevmode works (I checked it)

Comment: Thank you, I should've known there was a simple solution to this!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You comment seems to have solved the problem. Would you like to write an answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's often better to do the check in the first line of the paragraph rather than in vertical mode before the paragraph, that way teh check is more closely tied to the visual result.

Probably `\leavevmode` before `\checkoddpage` makes it do the right thing.